# How to avoid using namespace prefixes in Xaml

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, winui

I've started migrating company owned application from UWP 10 to WinUI (on NET5) using `upgrade-assistant` tool. Give or take, the most conflicts are gone, but the the nasty one remains in `.xaml` files. The underlying code can't be source-generated due to missing namespace prefixes:
[image]

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns:xaml="clr-namespace:Windows.UI.Xaml;assembly=Windows"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Ifs.Uma.UI.Controls">

    <Style TargetType="local:Dialog">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFEDEDED" />
    </Style>
    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing some package references. Or if it's possible to just define them somewhere (XmlnsDefinitionAttribute is not available)? Is it even possible without going through hundreds of .xaml files and fixing all them manually or via find-replace?

For example, one of `.csproj` files with referenced packages below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>SomeUI</RootNamespace>
    <DefaultLanguage>en</DefaultLanguage>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\FrameworkRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <AppxBundlePlatforms>x86|x64</AppxBundlePlatforms>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\FrameworkRules.Release.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>2.0.3</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.UpgradeAssistant.Extensions.Default.Analyzers" Version="0.3.330701">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

<!-- I had to add those manually to get the code working -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime" Version="4.3.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime" Version="4.7.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml" Version="4.7.0" />
        <Reference Include="Windows">
            <HintPath Condition="Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Facade\Windows.winMD')">C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Facade\Windows.winMD</HintPath>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract">
            <HintPath Condition="Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.19041.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\4.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd')">C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.19041.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\4.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd</HintPath>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract">
            <HintPath Condition="Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.19041.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\10.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd')">C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.19041.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\10.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd</HintPath>
        </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>        
</Project>
```

---

I've just went an obvious way, made a simple UWP program to add prefixes and namespaces to those tags (just in case someone's interested):

```cs
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        }

        private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // 1. run the following command to make your .xaml files accessible to UWP:
            //    XCOPY <your_solution_dir>/*.xaml C:\Users\<you>\Pictures\XAML /E
            // 2. Delete \bin and \obj directories from there (optional)
            // 3. Add Pictures capability to your manifest (imho the easiest one to use)
            //    <Capabilities>
            //      <uap:Capability Name = "picturesLibrary" />
            //    </Capabilities>
            var assembly = typeof(ResourceDictionary).Assembly;
            var regulars = assembly
                .GetExportedTypes()
                .Where(type => typeof(DependencyObject).IsAssignableFrom(type) && type.IsClass)
                .Select(type => new { Namespace = type.Namespace, TypeName = type.Name, Prefix = type.Namespace.Split('.').Last().ToLowerInvariant() })
                .GroupBy(x => x.Prefix)
                .Select(x => new { 
                    Regex = new Regex($"(</?)(?={string.Join("|", x.Select(n => n.TypeName))})"),
                    Replacements = x.Select(y => new Replacement(y.Namespace, y.Prefix)).First() })
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Regex, x => x.Replacements);
            var namespaceAttributes = new Regex("<(?<=[\b\\w\\d\\D]).*(xmlns)[^>]+", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            var picturesDirectory = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
            var sourceDirectory = await picturesDirectory.GetFolderAsync("XAML");
            var xamlFiles = await GetXamlFilesAsync(sourceDirectory);
            var fixedFiles = 0;
            foreach (var xamlFile in xamlFiles)
            {
                var markup = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(xamlFile);
                var matchedReplacements = new List<Replacement>();
                foreach (var replacer in regulars)
                {
                    if (replacer.Key.IsMatch(markup))
                    {
                        matchedReplacements.Add(replacer.Value);
                        markup = replacer.Key.Replace(markup, $"$&{replacer.Value.Prefix}:");
                    }
                }
                if (matchedReplacements.Count == 0) continue;
                var nsAttributes = namespaceAttributes.Match(markup);
                if (nsAttributes.Success && markup.Length > nsAttributes.Length)
                {
                    markup = nsAttributes.Result("$&" + Environment.NewLine +
                                string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                                matchedReplacements.Where(replacement => !markup.Contains($"xmlns:{replacement.Prefix}")).Select(replacement =>
                                $"xmlns:{replacement.Prefix}=\"clr-namespace:{replacement.Namespace};assembly=Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\"")))
                                + markup.Substring(nsAttributes.Length);
                }
                await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(xamlFile, markup);
                fixedFiles++;
            }
            await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog($"{fixedFiles} of {xamlFiles.Count} xaml files were fixed").ShowAsync();
        }

        async Task<IList<StorageFile>> GetXamlFilesAsync(StorageFolder topFolder)
        {
            var xamlFiles = new List<StorageFile>();
            var folders = await topFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
            foreach (var folder in folders)
            {
                xamlFiles.AddRange((await folder.GetFilesAsync()).Where(f => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(f.FileType, ".xaml")));
                xamlFiles.AddRange(await GetXamlFilesAsync(folder));
            }
            return xamlFiles;
        }

        private readonly struct Replacement
        {
            public Replacement(string @namespace, string prefix)
            {
                Namespace = @namespace; Prefix = prefix;
            }
            public readonly string Namespace;
            public readonly string Prefix;
        }
    }
```

```xml
<xaml:ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Ifs.Uma.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:nav="using:Ifs.Uma.UI.Navigation"
xmlns:xaml="clr-namespace:Windows.UI.Xaml;assembly=Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;assembly=Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract"
xmlns:shapes="clr-namespace:Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;assembly=Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract">

    <xaml:Style TargetType="local:PageHeader">
        <xaml:Setter Property="Height" Value="48" />
        <xaml:Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource IfsAppBackgroundBrush}" />
        <xaml:Setter Property="Template">
            <xaml:Setter.Value>
                <controls:ControlTemplate TargetType="local:PageHeader">
                    <controls:Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
<!-- Grid and other controls -->
                    </controls:Grid>
                </controls:ControlTemplate>
            </xaml:Setter.Value>
        </xaml:Setter>
    </xaml:Style>

</xaml:ResourceDictionary>
```

It all went fine, but resulted in a message that type `<controls:ControlTemplate />` does not support direct content. This type is pretty much within every .xaml file. `TemplateBinding` and other binding types also not found. Perhaps, it's not the way to fix the issue, there might be an SDK missing or something.

Comment: Unfortunately because you've taken a screenshot rather than showing the actual XAML, the tooltip is covering the most important parts. Please provide a minimal example of XAML that is causing the problem, *as text*.

Comment: Oops, haven't thought of that - updated! Basically, intellisense advises to change xaml reference to `xmlns:xaml="clr-namespace:Windows.UI.Xaml;assembly=Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract"` and add a namespace, like `<xaml:ResourceDictionary />`